# Flutter: Display a large amount of images without OOM

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to make a book reader, which would allow you to read only one book. This book has limited amount of pages(228), and I have urls to every page.

Now, I'm trying to display all of the images in the ListView, but it loads all images at once, and they're over 1GB in size, so the app crashes, saying out of memory error.

How would I free memory of the invisible items in the ListView and then load them again upon scrolling back to it?

My current code for building the LinearView is as following

```
new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Image.network(MyApp.imageLinks.values.elementAt(index));
          },),
        // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      );
```

But as I said, it throws an OOM error.

My device has 3GB of HW ram, which is not enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just like to note that 1GB is an absolutely _insane_ image size to attempt to load on a cell phone. You should strongly consider reducing the image resolution by many, many times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out of memory when displaying images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506036/out-of-memory-when-displaying-images-in-listview), although technically that one is probably a duplicate of this one. Looks like this was double posted.

Comment: @JonahWilliams I know this is a few years past, but 1GB was the size of all images together, not just a single one.
There were about 300 images, which were pages of a free book that could be found online and the app was meant to serve as a chapter-based guidebook.
1GB seems feasible for 300 images.

Comment: @MGlolenstine have you resolved this issue? Could you share any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to have a look at the package [extended_image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image).

> A powerful official extension library of image, which support
> placeholder(loading)/ failed state, cache network, zoom pan image,
> photo view, slide out page, editor(crop,rotate,flip), paint custom
> etc.

You can also check out this documentation about "[Loading images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-images)":

> Flutter can load resolution-appropriate images for the current device
> pixel ratio.

This idea was taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343674/images-in-listview-are-not-released-from-memory-when-out-of-view) which I think the same case on you.

> If you are fetching your images from network which is more likely,
> make sure their sizes are appropriate, and have different sizes served
> if you can. If you don't have control over that set `cacheWidth` and
> `cacheHeight` in `Image.memory` these will reduce the cached image in
> memory (RAM). **You see by default Flutter caches images in full
> resolution despite their apparent size in the device/app**. For
> example if you want your image to display in 200x200 box then set
> `cacheWidth` to `200 * window.devicePixelRatio.ceil()` you will find
> `window` in `dart:ui`, and if you only set `cacheWidth`, the ratio of
> your images will remain true. Same true if you only set `cacheHeight`.
> Also do use `ListView.builder` as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question :)
I've solved it by using placeholders, as the problem was that images were loaded as soon as the page was opened.
The reason for them all loading at once was due to an empty row being 0px tall and all of them were shown at once.